# AttributeError on socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import struct
import sys
import time

TIME1970 = 2208988800L  

client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
client.sendto( data, ( sys.argv[1], 123 ))
data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
if data:
    print 'Response received from:', address
    t = struct.unpack( '!12I', data )[10]
    t = TIME1970
    print '\tTime=%s' % time.ctime(t)
```

When I try to execute this script I'm getting the following error; please help me with this:

```
File "C:\Users\Wolverine\Desktop\Apcog-python prog\test.py", line 8, in ?
    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
AttributeError: socket
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 301, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\Wolverine\Desktop\Apcog-python prog\test.py", line 8, in ?
    client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
AttributeError: socket
```

Answer (score 1):

You imported `socket` as `from socket import socket`, together with other elements from that module, so you don't need to use the module name to refer to it:

```
client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Alternatively, change the import line to:

```
import socket
```

and continue referring to items from that module by attribute access.